# Logical error with writing to a file in C

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have a project I am working on, basically it requires me to read switches from the command line and reads and writes some output to the same file overwriting its previous content. If the file is not specified it reads from stdin and writes to stdout, here is a function to number all output lines:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) { 
     FILE *fp; 
     if((fp = fopen(argv[2]),"a+")) == 0) { 
            fp = stdin; /* if we cant read the file then it is read from stdin*/
     }
     if((strcmp("-e",argv[1])) == 0){
         if(fp == stdin) { 
              display_dollar(fp);  
         } 
     } 
    fclose(fp);
}
```

and this is my display_dollar function (the one that actually prints to stdout or fp)

```
void display_dollar(FILE *fp) { 
     char line[LINESIZE]; 
     char lines[LINESIZE];  
        while(fgets(line,LINESIZE,fp)) { 
            sscanf(line,"%s\n",lines);
            if(fp == stdin) { 
               printf("%s%c\n",lines,'$'); 
               lines[0] = '\0'; /* "clear" buffer */
            } else { 
               fprintf(fp,"%s%c\n",lines,'$'); 
               lines[0] = '\0'; /* "clear" buffer */
            } 
      }
}
```

This works perfectly for stdout but I am having trouble printing anything to the file specified by fp, I dont understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Some suggested i take out the parantheses when I compare fp but I get an compiler warning when I compile it with

```
gcc -ansi -W -Wall -pedantic
```

The warning as follows:

```
assign2.c: In function ‘main’:
assign2.c:20:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 if(fp = fopen(argv[argc - 1],"a+") == 0) {
     ^
 assign2.c:20:3: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
 if(fp = fopen(argv[argc - 1],"a+") == 0) {
 ^
```

Comment: What does `\n` do in `sscanf(line,"%s\n",lines);`?

Comment: Well, if I see this correctly, your display_dollar method is only doing stuff **IF AND ONLY IF**  *fp == stdin*. Thats whats the 'if' is saying in line 3 of *display_dollar*

Comment: @Manish @ameyCU i think that line should actually be:
`if(fp = fopen(argv[2],"a+") == 0)`

Comment: if((fp = fopen(argv[2]),"a+") == 0)  you are having an extra ' ) ' in this statement .Therefore causing error in opening file

Comment: @CorvinMcpherson exactly this is causing the  error.Removing that extra ')' will resolve this.

Comment: @ameyCU well removing a '(' at the start and ')' after argv[2]

Comment: You could also remove some ()'s in `if((strcmp("-e",argv[1])) == 0)` making it `if(strcmp("-e",argv[1]) == 0)`

Comment: @ckruczek I apologize that is a typo, that should not be there but its not the problem it still doesnt work as intended :(

Comment: @Manish Yes, it just solves part of the problem, im working on a full solution and should be available in a little while :)

Comment: @Manish is it a requirement that it overwrite the file in place?

Comment: @CorvinMcpherson, No it is not however, If im writing to the file I thought I might as well overwrite what I have instead of having the input and output in the same file

Comment: this code does not cleanly compile, amongst other warnings is that the parameter 'argc' is not used.    When the command line may contain parameters, the code needs to check 'argc' to assure the parameters exist.  Otherwise a reference to 'argv[x]' can be accessing almost anything, including address 0 (from the NULL entry at the end of the argv parameter list)   This results in undefined behaviour that can/will lead to a seg fault event,.

Comment: the posted code on calls display_dollar() if unable to open argv[2].  But the comments say that display_dollar() is called in either case

Answer (score 2):

#### Original code

Look very carefully at this line — it doesn't do what you want:

```
if((fp = fopen(argv[2]),"a+") == 0) {
   ^          ^       ^     ^
   1          2       2     1
```

The parentheses aren't paired up as you intend.  You're not passing enough arguments to `fopen()`.  And you're comparing `"a+"` with `0`.

You really want:

```
if ((fp = fopen(argv[2], "a+")) == 0) {
```

#### Revised code

In the revised code, you seem to have:

```
if(fp = fopen(argv[argc - 1],"a+") == 0) {
```

This is parsed as:

```
if (fp = (fopen(argv[argc - 1], "a+") == 0)) {
```

It is assigning the 0 or 1 result of comparing the return value from `fopen()` with 0, and that isn't a pointer, hence the complaint about `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`.

The second warning about `suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value` is indicative of the problem; the result of the assignment is used as the condition, which is only sometimes correct (and this is one of the times when it isn't).  It more usually appears in a context such as:

```
if (i = j)
```

where you probably intended:

```
if (i == j)
```

but if you really wanted to test the assignment, then you should write:

```
if ((i = j) != 0)
```

or (perish the thought — I hate it when people do this!):

```
if ((i = j))
```

#### Still having problems…

> but it still won't write to the file,

You have a single read/write position in a file.  You are reading from and writing to the same file, `fp`.  If that is `stdin`, you've go one set of problems; if it is a regular text file, you have another set.

First of all, between a read and a write (or a write and a read) on a file opened for update, you must do a positioning operation — `fseek()` or `rewind()`, mainly.  Secondly, because you opened the file in append mode, all writes occur at the end of the file.  That means that when you try to read after a write, the position is at the end of the file (aka EOF).

If the file is standard input, that is often not seekable, which has implications, too.  Standard input (or, at least, the underlying file descriptor 0 on Unix) is very often writable, but that's not something you're supposed (ab)use like that.

- You either need to have an input file and an output file, or you need to be seeking appropriately.

And maybe you want `"r+"` instead of `"a+"` mode.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, That was also a typo :( i apologize I made sure everything else is correct, I realized that might have been the problem before I shared it on here but it still wont write to the file, Im thinking it may be the else block that contains the fprinf perhaps the program doesnt make it there, thank you for your input and i apologize again

Answer (score 0):

Alright, long story short I rewrote the code to have an input and output file, because things would get more complicated overwriting the current file in place without using a buffer.

Please let me know if there are any issues, or if things need to be explained.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINESIZE 1024

void display_dollar(FILE *, FILE *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *infp = stdin;
  FILE *outfp = stdout;
  for (int i = 4; i < argc; ++i)
    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown argument: %s\n", argv[i]);
  if (argc >= 4 && (outfp = fopen(argv[3], "w")) == NULL)
    outfp = stdout;
  if (argc >= 3 && (infp = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL)
    infp = stdin;
  if (argc >= 2 && strcmp("-e", argv[1]) == 0)
    display_dollar(infp, outfp);
  else
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -e [infile [outfile]]\n", argc ? argv[0] : "program");
  fclose(infp);
  fclose(outfp);
  return 0;
}

void remove_newlines(char *str) {
  for(long i = strlen(str)-1; i >= 0 && (str[i] == '\n' || str[i] == '\r'); --i)
    str[i] = '\0';
}

void display_dollar(FILE *infp, FILE *outfp) {
  char line[LINESIZE];
  while (fgets(line, LINESIZE, infp)) {
    remove_newlines(line);
    fprintf(outfp, "%s%c\n", line, '$');
  }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to look at your argument handling, I think.  If I don't provide `-e` as argument 1, you're not going to do anything (and you're not going to tell the user that you'll do nothing).  If I provide more than 3 arguments (so argc > 4), then you're going to ignore the excess.  That's probably not the best idea, though it is not wholly indefensible.

Comment: Other than the argument handling, that looks OK to me.  If any line is longer than your maximum, you'll end up splitting that line every 1023 characters.  That's a pretty reasonable decision (but look at POSIX's [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function for an alternative).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the feedback, I will add some messages to address the argument issues. As for the maximum line size I will stick with the current fgets() setup for resource limiting purposes and to keep to just the C standard.

Comment: fopen() returns a pointer, not a integer.  So the comparison should be to NULL, not 0   When compiled with the warnings enabled, the compiler will tell you about this problem.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for catching that however, I am using gcc 4.9.2-10 and it does not warn about this with your options.

Answer (score 0):

this code:

```
void display_dollar(FILE *fp) { 
     char line[LINESIZE]; 
     char lines[LINESIZE];  
        while(fgets(line,LINESIZE,fp)) { 
            sscanf(line,"%s\n",lines);
            if(fp == stdin) { 
               printf("%s%c\n",lines,'$'); 
               lines[0] = '\0'; /* "clear" buffer */
            } else { 
               fprintf(fp,"%s%c\n",lines,'$'); 
               lines[0] = '\0'; /* "clear" buffer */
            } 
      }
}

1) changes the number of characters in the next line, so the output file will be corrupted.
2) each read/write to the file moves the file-position-pointer.
   you could use ftell() to see this happening.
3) the code must not corrupt the file, so it will have to write a new file.
4) this has a logic error, the %s will stop when any white space is encountered.  
This includes newlines (of which there will (almost) always be one
or any tab or any space.
then appending a '$' will overlay something in the line.
therefore, the line to output will be corrupted.
the corruption could be a space or a NUL or a tab or a newline being overlayed

Suggestions:
1)  When outputting to a file, always create a new file
2)  always find the newline with strstr() (or similar), overlay the newline with "$\0",
    then strcat()  "\n\0"
```

this will mean modifying the display_dollar() declaration to include both the input and output file pointers

Comment: the last line in the input file 'may' not have a trailing newline.  the code will need to allow for that.